# How to activate an Automator application with AppleScript?

Tags: applescript, automator

Why does this fail to open the application?

```
try
    open application "Macintosh HD:Users:TheUser:Desktop⁩⁩:Automator test 2"
on error
    display dialog "could not open the automator"
end try
```

I've also tried the following:

```
tell application "Macintosh HD:Users:TheUser:Desktop⁩⁩:Automator test 2" to activate

tell application "finder" to activate "Macintosh HD:Users:TheUser:Desktop⁩⁩:Automator test 2"
```

The file path is correct and the application works when activated manually.

Comment: I'm surprised there's no file extension.  Is the absence of one something intentional ?

Answer (score 1):

I was being stupid. This version works:

```
tell application "Finder"
    try
        open "Macintosh HD:Users:TheUser:Desktop⁩⁩:Automator test 2"
    on error
        display dialog "could not open the automator"
    end try
end tell
```

Just have to use the tell finder command and open instead of open application.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `do shell script` and calling the [`automator`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/automator/) command-line tool.